# Delphi default "New" Project

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

When I create a new project using menu File->New->VCL Forms Application what I get is an old project.  Its something that I have done but I cannot find what, searching does not give me any relevant answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can set it under Tools -> Options, on the Environment Options page, there you can set a Default Project file.

(This is Delphi XE2, but I guess it hasn't changed in later versions.)

[image: Default Project setting]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the "Default Project" option is only for the folder that is, by default, the location in which projects are saved.